# how to set title and height to tab host in android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a question that I am implementing a tab in my android app but Tab host not displays title.

I use the following code  in XML

```
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="63dip"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please tell how to display title and set the size to tab host in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you look [here.](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136)

Basically, you create a custom layout(This is all from that link BTW):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#A8A8A8" android:centerColor="#7F7F7F"
        android:endColor="#696969" android:angle="-90" />
</shape>
```

Then you inflate it. Since I don't want to do straight-up plagiarism, just check the link.